yolov9 with gpu on PC
Hello i have a problem or maybe more of a question. Im working on a object detection project i trained my yolov9 model and now i want to test it. But every time i test it i have low fps on my webcam. its using my cpu instead of gpu .
`Ultralytics YOLOv8.2.48  Python-3.12.4 torch-2.3.1+cpu CPU (AMD Ryzen 7 5800H with Radeon Graphics)
YOLOv9c summary (fused): 384 layers, 25321561 parameters, 0 gradients, 102.3 GFLOPs
`

also when i test for gpu i get :

`import torch
print(torch.__version__)

if torch.cuda.is_available():
  print(f"GPU Name: {torch.cuda.get_device_name(0)}")
  print(f"GPU Is Available: {torch.cuda.is_available()}")
else:
  print("GPU is not available")`

2.3.1+cpu
GPU is not available
is there a way to make it faster not 1 frame per 2 seconds :/
i tried isntaling cuda, i want to use gpu for faster image processing

Check on Nvidia's website if you GPU is compatible with to use CUDA. Then install torch version to use GPU version. In PyTorch website you can select exactly what CUDA version and what hardware (GPU/CPU) you want it to run as default.
If you GPU is not compatible and you have to use CPU than not much you can do here. Could try some workaround with Google's Colab but I'm not sure if that would work

I fixed the problem of torch not seeing my GPU. Pytorch was installed with: pip install ultralytics
I reinstalled CUDA and then I reinstalled torch with the following command:
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu121

